# Where does log(n) come from in the O(N) notation

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, big-o

I know what is O(n) notation and I also understand how I can get notations like O(n), O(n<sup>2</sup>), ....

- O(n) means I have to get through sequence once
- O(n<sup>2</sup>) means that I have two nested cycles traversing sequence

But how do I get log(N)?

P.S.: I know the Collections API and some classes that have O(n log n) traversal time. I need a simple explanation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Answer (score 12, accepted):

lg *N* comes about in divide-and-conquer algorithms, where you iteratively or recursively skip half of the data in a collection of *N* items. [Binary search](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is the quintessential example. The insert, lookup and delete operations on binary search trees are also O(lg *N*).

Iteratively discarding half the elements is, in an intuitive sense, the inverse of iteratively doubling the number of elements. Doubling would produce O(2^*N*) elements in *N* iterations. Note that the binary logarithm of *N* is the inverse of raising two to the power *N*.

Sorting an array can be done in O(*N* lg *N*) by algorithms such as mergesort, but also conceptually simpler: iterate over the array and put the elements in a binary search tree. Each insert takes O(lg *N*) and there are *N* of them, so the algorithm runs in O(*N* lg *N*).

(The sort-by-BST even has worst-case O(*N* lg *N*) complexity if the tree is [balanced](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).)

Comment: To be exact "comparision sorts" can only be done in O(n Log n), if you throw out that limitation, you can sort an array in O(n).

Answer (score 3):

Best example **N*log(N)** in my opinion would be to look at comparison based search:

Lets take [merge-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) as an example.

The algorithm takes an array of elements, splits it by 2 recursively until it get an array of length 2, then merges back the pieces at O(n) each merging sorted arrays is easier.

Ok, that was a nutshell description, now lets see what it looks like:

```
  [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]  
           |  
           /\  
  [1 2 3 4]  [ 5 6 7 8 ]
      |             |
      /\            /\
[1 2 ] [ 3 4]   [5 6] [7 8]
```

What I hope you can see here, that the **depth** of the recursion is log(n) (Because it's a tree that has 2 branches... so it's log(n) with base 2)
But in each **level** of the tree there's O(n) operations (because we are actively re-arranging n object).

So there a **N*log(N)** complexity here.

Most algorithms that have Log(N) complexity get that from a tree-based algorithm.
There are a few that are just probabilistic log(n) (which means that after a long math computation you get that in average it would be something like log(n))

Answer (score 2):

A typical algorithm with complexity O(log n) is binary search in a sorted array. Instead of stepping through each element one by one `O(n)` you iteratively split you array in half and only look in the half where you know your element can be.